# React Native onScroll problem when holding my finger up to ScrollView

Tags: react-native

```
<ScrollView 
onScroll={(event)=>{
  const top = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y;
  setTop(top);
}}
>
```

With my code above contentOffset y updated only when scroll ScrollView abruptly without holding my finger up to ScrollView but if I hold my finger up when scroll the contentOffset y doesn't updated.

I noticed this happening for all onScroll function.

What I want to achieve:
I want on scroll ScrollView contentOffset y update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Animated.ScrollView instead of ScrollView maybe help you. Have a look at this https://eveningkid.medium.com/animated-and-react-native-scrollviews-de701f1b1ce5